# Why doesn't my 2nd shape appear in my JAVA program using awt?

Tags: java, swing, oop

```
public class Pong {

    private static final int ICON_HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final MoveableShape SHAPE = new Paddle(15, 0, PADDLE_WIDTH);
        final MoveableShape SHAPE2 = new Paddle(50, 50, PADDLE_WIDTH);

        IconShape icon = new IconShape(SHAPE, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
        IconShape icon2 = new IconShape(SHAPE2, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.black );
        frame.add(label,label2);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final  int DELAY = 50;

        Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, actionEvent -> {
            SHAPE.translate(0, 1);
            SHAPE2.translate(0,1);
            label.repaint();
            label2.repaint();
        });

        t.start();
    }
}
```

Shape appears on screen as a white rectangle, and basically I would like a second instance of Shape on the other side of the screen like in Pong, but for some reason, Shape2 won't show up in the frame. Any ideas why this might be the case? I'm pretty new to awt.

Comment: You are using Swing components, not AWT components. Swing components start with a "J".

Comment: For more help post [mre]

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.add(label,label2);
```

Well, you are using a FlowLayout so the two components should be displayed beside one another.

```
final MoveableShape SHAPE = new Paddle(15, 0, PADDLE_WIDTH);
final MoveableShape SHAPE2 = new Paddle(50, 50, PADDLE_WIDTH);

IconShape icon = new IconShape(SHAPE, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
IconShape icon2 = new IconShape(SHAPE2, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
```

However, it also looks like you are doing custom painting. So you custom painting is wrong. Custom painting is always done relative to (0, 0) of the component, not relative to the panel you add the component to.

That is I'm guessing because you specify (50, 50...) for the second shape it is painted outside the size of the icon so you don't see the painting. Since (15, 0...) works on your first icon try those values.

That should solve your first problem.

However, the bigger problem is that the layout manager will control the location of the component, not your application. So you really need to redesign the code to do custom painting of all your objects so you can fully control the location of each object.

Start with custom painting basics by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for some example.